# Convert string currency to float with ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following string:

"1.273,08"

And I need to convert to float and the result must be:

1273.08

I tried some code using gsub but I can't solve this.
How can I do this conversion?

Answer (score 5):

You have already received two good answers how to massage your [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) into your desired format using [`String#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-delete) and [`String#tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-tr).

But there is a deeper problem.

The decimal value 1 273.08<sub>10</sub> *cannot* be accurately represented as an IEEE 754-2019 / ISO/IEC 60559:2020 *binary64* floating point value.

Just like the value 1/3rd can easily be represented in ternary (0.1<sub>3</sub>) but has an infinite representation in decimal (0.33333333…<sub>10</sub>, i.e. 0.[3]…<sub>10</sub>) and thus cannot be accurately represented, the value 8/100th can easily be represented in decimal (0.08<sub>10</sub>) but has an infinite representation in binary (0.0001010001111010111000010100011110101110000101…<sub>2</sub>, i.e. 0.[00010100011110101110]…<sub>2</sub>). In other words, it is *impossible* to express 1 273.08<sub>10</sub> as a Ruby [`Float`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html).

And that's not specific to Ruby, or even to programming, that is just basic high school maths: you *cannot* represent this number in binary, *period*, just like you cannot represent 1/3rd in decimal, or π in any integer base.

And of course, computers don't have infinite memory, so not only does 1 273.08<sub>10</sub> have an infinite representation in binary, but as a `Float`, it will also be cut off after 64 bits. The closest possible value to 1 273.08<sub>10</sub> as an IEEE 754-2019 / ISO/IEC 60559:2020 *binary64* floating point value is 1 273.079 999 999 999 927 240 423 858 17<sub>10</sub>, which is *less than* 1 273.08<sub>10</sub>.

That is why you should *never* represent money using binary numbers: everybody will expect it to be decimal, not binary; if I write a cheque, I write it in decimal, not binary. People will expect that it is impossible to represent $ 1/3rd, they will expect that it is impossible to represent $ π, but they will *not* expect and not *accept* that if they put $ 1273.08 into their account, they will actually end up with slightly less than that.

The *correct* way to represent money would be to use a specialized `Money` datatype, or at least using the [`bigdecimal`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/index.html) library from the standard library:

```ruby
require 'bigdecimal'

BigDecimal('1.273,08'.delete('.').tr(',', '.'))
#=> 0.127308e4
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
"1.273,08".delete('.')   # delete '.' from the string  
          .tr(',', '.')  # replace ',' with '.'
          .to_f          # translate to float
#=> 1273.08
```

Answer (score 0):

So, we're using `.` as a thousands separator and `,` instead of a dot:

```
str = "1.273,08"
str.gsub('.','').gsub(',', '.').to_f
```

Comment: alternately `str.gsub(/[.,]/,{',' => '.'}).to_f`

Comment: @engineersmnky, now that's interesting. I had been thinking `"1.273,08".gsub(/[.,]/, ','=>'.', '.'=>'').to_f`, but you've shown me that `, '.'=>''` is not needed, something I didn't know (and I've shown you that you don't need `{` and `}`, something that you did know).

Comment: @CarySwoveland how about this instead `tr('.,','_.')` since ruby recognizes `_` as a valid thousands separator.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I like.